# ¿Cómo comparar elementos de distintas dimensiones en array multidimensionales?

Tags: python, array, indices

Quiero comparar el elemento **SL** de mi lista, en tal medida de que **SL** no esté "abajo" de **SR**.

Es decir, que en la función: encuentre en tal índice a **SL**, y luego pase a la siguiente lista para encontrar a **SR** en la misma altura:

si **SR** está en el mismo índice en la siguiente lista con respecto a **SL**, entonces retorna **False**.

```py
lista = 
[
    ["1","SC","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["2","SL","SC","SC","SA","SC"],
    ["3","SR","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["4","SA","SL","SC","SC","SR","SC"]
]
```

Mi función:

```py
def funcion(lista):
    sr=0
    sl=0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(6):
            if ed[i][j] == "SL":
                 """aquí"""
   return True
```

**OUTPUT (fijarse en SL y SR número 2 y 3):**

```
    ["1","SC","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["2","SL","SC","SC","SA","SC"],
    ["3","SR","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["4","SA","SL","SC","SC","SR","SC"]

la función retorna False
```

```
    ["1","SC","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["2","SC","SC","SC","SA","SC"],
    ["3","SR","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["4","SA","SL","SC","SC","SR","SC"]

la función retorna True
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente a lo que te refieres con que no esté "abajo".
¿Si encuentra **SL** en la posición [2,3], devuelve False si se **SR** encuentra en la [3,3]?

Comment: @RuDaHee por eso lo expliqué de otra manera. Si SL está en la lista [0] posición [1], "debajo" sería SR en la lista [1] posición [1].

Comment: Quizá, (muy probable) que yo  tome la traspuesta  , luego tome cada fila la junte como un join y aplique un expresión regular que evalúe  la evalúe SR luego de SL retorne true o false. Me evito manejar indice+1  .es una idea. Se debe quizá hacer un par de conversiones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Buenas!

Creo que ya he localizado lo que quieres realizar con el código.

Te voy a comentar por puntos

- El corchete de listas debe ir detrás del igual y no una linea por debajo.
- He cambiado esta condición `if (lista[i][j] == "SL") and i != 3`, para que si la encuentra en la lista 4 no intente comparar debajo, ya que ahí es imposible que se encuentre y arrojaría un error por salirse del rango.
- He agregado esta condición `if lista[i+1][j] == "SR":` que comprueba que debajo de donde ya había encontrado un "SL" existe un "SR", si la condición se cumple, le dará el valor verdadero a una variable (*bandera*) que he declarado anteriormente como false. Por tanto, si encuentra un "SR" debajo de un "SL" devolverá True, de cualquier otra forma, siempre devolverá False.
- Si por el contrario quieres que devuelva True **si no esta debajo** solo debes invertir la variable *bandera* tanto en la declaración como cuando se le asigna valor en la ultima comparación. Otra opción, aunque me gusta menos, es hacer `return !bandera`.

Aquí te dejo el código.

```py
lista = [
    ["1","SC","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["2","SL","SC","SC","SA","SC"],
    ["3","SR","SC","SC","SC","SC"],
    ["4","SA","SL","SC","SC","SR","SC"]
]


def funcion(lista):
    bandera = False
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(6):
            if (lista[i][j] == "SL") and i != 3:
                if lista[i+1][j] == "SR":
                    bandera = True

    return bandera


print(funcion(lista))
```

Espero que te sirva. ¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Otra solucion sin bucles (yo es que soy muy de one-liners ;)):

```
import pandas as pd
def check_SL_SR(lista):
    return any(pd.DataFrame(lista).sum().str.contains('SLSR', regex=False))
```

Si transformamos la lista en un dataframe y hacemos la suma, nos concatena las cadenas de forma vertical, por lo que si hay un SL y abajo un SR aparecera la subcadena SLSR. Despues solo hay que buscar esa subcadena en todas las sumas y reportar si alguna (any) ha visto el patron.